# How to create a filter and add query params to all links

Tags: query

I have been trying for days and cannot get it to work

I wish to create simple filter than can add 2 parameters to every link on the entire site.
I would prefer that I can control only links have /external/ in their url is affected

I wish to add id=[id] and referrer=URL of the current page

Hope for a little help :-)

Comment: Is `ID` the post ID or something different? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean `$post->ID`, you can use the [`post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/) and [`post_type_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) filters to append your query string. We're using the [`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) function to do this:

```
/**
 * Modify the posts navigation WHERE clause
 * to include our acceptable post types
 * 
 * @param String $post_link - Post URL
 * @param WP_Post $post - Current Post
 * 
 * @return String
 */
function wpse375877_link_referrer( $post_link, $post ) {
    
    // Return Early
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    
    return add_query_arg( array(
        'id'        => $post->ID,
        'referrer'  => $post_link,
    ) );
    
}
add_filter( 'post_link',        'wpse375877_link_referrer', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link',   'wpse375877_link_referrer', 20, 2 );
```

The above ensures that any WordPress functions will be given a modified post URL. Now, if we wanted to redirect any URLs missing this query string, you can use [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) action hook:

```
/**
 * Redirect any items without query string
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse375877_redirect_to_referrer() {
    
    if( ! isset( $_GET, $_GET['id'], $_GET['referrer'] ) ) {
        
        wp_safe_redirect(
            add_query_arg( array(
                'id'        => get_the_ID(),
                'referrer'  => get_permalink(),
            ), get_permalink() )
        );
        exit();
        
    }
    
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse375877_redirect_to_referrer' );
```

I'm not 100% sure if I should be using [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on these URLs or not.

Comment: It works for "normal" links but in this page https://www.knib.dk/knibeoevelser/ I have 2 green buttons (a shortcode) that uses a link which is prettylink. How can this work for those or all links containing /link/ in the url

Comment: @lennartoester It's difficult to say. You would need to figure out how those shortcodes are generating those links and edit your question. If they're being generated by a plugin then there may not be a consistent way to append the parameters so it really depends.